# Why in Pandas DataFrame with mix elements types, when I change an element I get "ValueError"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So Imagine that I have a dataframe as bellow (import pandas as pd, import numpy as np):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6]), np.array([7,8,9]), np.array([10,11,12]), np.array([13,14,15])], 'b':[5,5,12,123,5]})
```

Now If I want to replace the 3 element in column 'a' using:

```
df.loc[2,'a']= np.array([53,23,4])
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-67-4741bddaf261>", line 1, in <module>
    df.loc[0,'a']= np.array([53,23,4])
  File "...", line 205, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "...", line 547, in _setitem_with_indexer
    "Must have equal len keys and value "

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Now If I remove the second column ('b') and make my dataframe as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6]), np.array([7,8,9]), np.array([10,11,12]), np.array([13,14,15])]})
```

and use exactly previous command to replace the 3rd item, I will not receive any error.
What am I doing wrong here? What is the better practice to not have this error?

P.S. I am using Python 3.7.5 on ubuntu 18.10 and Pycharm IDE (2019.3.3). The version of my pandas is 0.25.3, numpy is 1.17.3 .

Comment: This looks like a bug to me and you should report this, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks Erfan for the response. I do not have enough insight about it to know if I am making a mistake and it is suppose to be like this or this is a bug.

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug, especially since `df['a'][2]` is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.at` as you are trying to access a single value. `df.loc` allows you to access multiple rows and columns which is where the problem may lie, though I am not entirely sure. Check out the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html).

```
df.at[2,'a'] = np.array([52,23,34])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I do this in my code as a way around. But I still get the 'SettingWithCopyWarning' and as I understand it is not always a bad practice to get this warning but I was wondering if there is a better way of addressing it without a need to turn off the warning or ignoring it. And the other maybe more important question is why using "loc" is not working?

Comment: You can use `df.at[2,'a'] = np.array([52,23,34])` since you are trying to access a single value. `df.at` allows you to access a single value whereas `df.loc` allows you to access a group of rows and columns, this is where the problem may be. Take a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html). I hope that helps.